# How to sync file times from one directory tree to another

Tags: linux, sync, timestamp

I have two file trees. The first one consist of original files. The second one is a duplicate but lacking correct file timestamps, they are all set to the last duplication date.

Is there a clean and easy way to copy the file timestamps from one tree to another, without transferring the files contents again?

Add on: The two trees may differ slightly in some files, as the duplicate where made at some point in the past. The timestamps should just be updated when possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try with:

```
cd /path/to/old/directory

find . -exec touch "/path/to/new/directory/{}" --reference "{}" \;
```

`touch --reference someotherfile` changes the date and time of a file by using `someotherfile` as reference.

If the trees are identical, then the {} part will be expanded to the same file in both trees, and the new directory prefix will do the rest. You can use `echo` instead of `touch` to verify that the correct files are being walked.

Of course this executes a `touch` process for every file. Possibly a Python script would work more efficiently.

Comment: This works well, except it is a little slow as you stated. Suprisingly, it does makes several hundred files per second, which is quite cool if you remember a new `touch` is run for every file.. however, I will try a Python script like you propose.

Answer (score 3):

A short python script will do:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys

for directory,subdirs,files in os.walk('.'):
    pathes=subdirs+files
    for path in pathes:
        fullpath=os.path.join(directory,path)
        target_path=os.path.join(sys.argv[1],fullpath)
        mtime=os.lstat(fullpath).st_mtime
        print 'touching',target_path,':',
        try:
            os.utime(target_path,(mtime,mtime))
            print 'OK'
        except:
            print 'FAILED'
```

it has to be run in the source dir, given the target dir as the only argument, eg.:

`python ~/sync_tstamps.py /path/to/target_dir`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `rsync` and its `--size-only` option.

```
rsync -avi --size-only A/ B/
```

This should only check the files' sizes and update the timestamps.

Comment: On some systems, the timestamps might only *look* identical, but have a sub-second drift (you can check with `ls --full-time`), since the timestamp set by `rsync` is exact at the seconds level (i.e. 12:34:45.0000) while the filesystem might set it at the microseconds level). In such cases, a second `rsync` in the opposite direction might be required.

Comment: Looks cool. I also added `--existing` to prevent rsync copying files again that where deleted after the duplication.

Comment: Even when using `--existing`, there is still some risk loosing modifications made to some files since the duplication. Maybe there is some way preventing rsync from copying content at all? Then the problem would shrink to some resetted timestamps. On the other hand, using rsync without `--size-only` would give a precise picture of what files would need a new timestamp and which do not. Using with `-n` for dry run, I would get a list stating `>f` for files that would be reseted but should not, and `.f.t` for files that are old and would get the correct old timestamp. But how to apply it then?

Comment: That seems to be a dead end. rsync works well if the trees are identical except the timestamps, but if there are any other changes, it gets too complicated to keep rsync from applying them either.